# Azure pipelines failing stating Incorrect task refrence

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines-tasks

My Azure pipeline is as below:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
steps:
- task: terraform init
  displayName: 'terraform init'
  inputs:
    provider: aws
    backendServiceAWS: 'tcp-aws-aa'
    backendAWSBucketName: 'terraform-backend-20200102'
    backendAWSKey: dev.plan

- task: terraform fmt
  displayName: 'terraform fmt'
  inputs:
    provider: aws
    command: fmt
    
- task: terraform validate
  displayName: 'terraform validate'
  inputs:
    provider: aws
    command: validate

- task: terraform plan
  displayName: 'terraform plan'
  inputs:
    provider: aws
    command: plan
    environmentServiceNameAWS: 'tcp-aws-aa'

- task: tflint check
  inputs:
    script: tflint .

- task: tfsec check
  inputs:
    script: tfsec .
```

However, it produces an error as like below

[image]

How to have it resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like you want to refer to `task: TerraformTaskV1@0` (based on the syntax) and the you should use as this:

```yaml
- task: TerraformTaskV1@0
  inputs:
    provider: 'azurerm'
    command: 'init'
    backendAWSKey: 
    backendAWSBucketName:
```

It support these commands:

[image]

And of course to use it you need to install [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks). I guessed that this is the one you should use based on the input settings. They are exactly the same like this extension has.

You also have there `tflint` and `tfsec` but I didn't found extensions or native solution for them so assuming that you installed them on agent you should rather use them like this:

```yaml
- script: |
    tflint .
  displayName: 'tflint check'

- script: |
    tfsec .
  displayName: 'tfsec check'
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however, where it is written to refer to TerraformTaskV1@0 ? and also the later syntax? where do I need to check? Please guide.

Comment: Please check my edit. I added there info out this. If you have more question feel free to ask.